# How to create a chained dropdown and dynamically display results based on city/state?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I need 2 chained dropdowns, city and state, that would populate a list after choosing the city. So basically a user would be presented with a dropdown to choose a state (US) which would lead to another dropdown to choose the city. After choosing the city it would populate a list that I would have created based on the city/state choice. It is a WordPress site and I was hoping there is a plugin that someone might know of to make this easier. The list will be rather large so I'd prefer to do it in the backend of WordPress if possible, but I can do it all in a template file with HTML if I have to. Has anyone encountered anything similar? What might a good solution be, WP plugin or other?

Comment: lots of client side plugins and tutorials around for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```js
var citiesByState = {
  USA: ["NY", "NJ"],
  Singapore: ["taas", "naas"]
}

function makeSubmenu(value) {
  if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var citiesOptions = "";
    for (cityId in citiesByState[value]) {
      citiesOptions += "<option>" + citiesByState[value][cityId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = citiesOptions;
  }
}

function resetSelection() {
  document.getElementById("countrySelect").selectedIndex = 0;
  document.getElementById("citySelect").selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="resetSelection()">
  <select id="countrySelect" size="1" onchange="makeSubmenu(this.value)">
    <option></option>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>Singapore</option>
  </select>
  <select id="citySelect" size="1">
    <option></option>
  </select>
</body>
```

> **Note:** The options you add in HTML like `<option>India</option>` must have same name and same cases in JavaScript `array` like `India: ["Gujarat","AP"]`

**Update :**

```js
var citiesByState = {
    USA: ["NY", "NJ"],
    Singapore: ["taas", "naas"]
}

function makeSubmenu(value) {
    if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
    else {
        var citiesOptions = "";
        for (cityId in citiesByState[value]) {
            citiesOptions += "<option id=" + citiesByState[value][cityId] + ">" + citiesByState[value][cityId] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = citiesOptions;
    }
}

function makeDisplay(curId)
{
   var curId = curId[curId.selectedIndex].id;
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('allbox');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
   document.getElementById('box'+ curId + '').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.allbox {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<select id="countrySelect" size="1" onchange="makeSubmenu(this.value)">
    <option disabled selected ></option>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>Singapore</option>
</select>
<select id="citySelect" size="1" onchange="makeDisplay(this)">
    <option></option>
</select>
<div class="allbox" id="boxNY">Some Text... for Ny</div>

<div class="allbox" id="boxNJ">Some Text... for NJ</div>
```

Comment: I found several plugins that take me this far, but how would I display <div id="ny">Test1</div> if I chose say USA > NY?

Comment: Is this div independent to select box on page?

Comment: yes. There would would be a list in a div for New York, a list in a div for LA etc. that would need to be displayed after selecting that city.

Comment: @jfoutch I have updated the Answer, with snippet just shown you demo for NY and NJ. Still if you have any issues feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes, thank you for helping me understand this. Now I can go over your code and understand exactly what is happening.

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Comment: Also change this line: `var citiesOptions = "";` in else loop to `var citiesOptions = "<option selected disabled></option>";`.

Comment: Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/scofq01z/1/